# ¿Porque visual code no me reconoce jsx?

Tags: reactjs

Escribo este código y me marca error desde que abro el primer div y al intentar correrlo me aparece el siguiente error

ERROR in ./src/components/header.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Code\coda\contact\src\components\header.js: Unexpected token (5:8)

Acaso necesito algún componente?

```
> import React from 'react'

const Header = () => {
    return {
        <div className="ui fixed menu">
            <div className="ui container center">
                <h2>contact manager</h2>
            </div> 
        </div>
    };
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el `return` debes poner el código entre paréntesis, y no entre corchetes, ese es el principal problema.

```
import React from 'react'

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className="ui fixed menu">
            <div className="ui container center">
                <h2>contact manager</h2>
            </div> 
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```